# php websocket at BINANCE FUTURES does not work

Tags: php, websocket, binance, phpwebsocket, binance-api-client

I'm having trouble connecting to binance futures' websocket server in php.

In the example below in BINANCE SPOT it works:

```
<?php
$sock = stream_socket_client("tls://stream.binance.com:9443",$error,$errnum,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,stream_context_create(null));
if (!$sock) {
    echo "[$errnum] $error" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'Conected!';
}
```

But in the example below in BINANCE FUTURES it doesn't work. Does not connect to server.

```
<?php
$sock = stream_socket_client("tls://fstream.binance.com",$error,$errnum,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,stream_context_create(null));
if (!$sock) {
    echo "[$errnum] $error" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo 'Conected!';
}
```

The error message reported is this:

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://fstream.binance.com (Failed to parse address "fstream.binance.com") in D:\p_local\atual\ws\wsf.php on line 2

Does anyone know why the second option doesn't work?

link to futures binance websockets documentation: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams

*I'm using native php server in command line in windows environment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"it doesn't work:"_ is not a problem description. Explain what happens, what you expect to happen, and include the complete text of any error messages you see.

Comment: Does not connect to server.
The error message reported is this:

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://fstream.binance.com (Failed to parse address "fstream.binance.com") in D:\p_local\atual\ws\wsf.php on line 2

Comment: You need a port

Comment: No port defined in futures binance docimentation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's late, but you have to use port 443

```
tls://fstream.binance.com:443
```

Comment: It works. Thanks!